# Datepicker not working inside dynamically created input

Tags: jquery, laravel, datepicker

I use a Datepicker and I have an `input` created with jQuery. The Datepicker does not work, but work with any normal `input` it works. When I click the input it does not show any thing.

```js
$('.add-victim-row').on('click', function() {
  addVictimRow();
})

function addVictimRow() {
  var tr = '<tr>' +
    '<input type="text" class="form-control myDate-picker" id="victim_dob" name="victim_dob[]" autocomplete="off" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td><span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm victim-remove-row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></td>' +
    '</tr>';

  $('.victim-table tbody').append(tr)
}
```

Comment: You need to initialise the datepicker on the new content you add to the DOM, just like you did when the page loaded

Comment: how you apply `datepicker` to any input ?

Comment: It  seems that it could be problem with the same id `victim_dob`

Comment: Thank yout my brother use code inside function datepicker work but change only first input

Comment: you need to give dynamic class or id of input

Comment: How is it done ?please help to the importance of the topic

Answer (score 0):

try this:

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
  });
});
```

html:

```
<label>Date</label>
<input id="datepicker1" name="date">
```